# How to select a column of table when I click on "choose me"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, dom

Here is a table example from my project. How can I select the whole table column when I click on "choose me"?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>plan 1</th>
    <th>plan 2</th>
    <th>plan 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>plan 1 detail</td>
    <td>plan 2 detail</td>
    <td>plan 3 detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>plan 1 detail</td>
    <td>plan 2 detail</td>
    <td>plan 3 detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>choose me!</td>
    <td>choose me!</td>
    <td>choose me!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I click on "choose me", I want to get style of column design to be changed.

Please help.

Comment: what exactly your requirement is ? do you want to change the style of column or cell ?

Comment: i want to change style of coloumn for plan is clicked on choose me!

Comment: is clicked on column of pan 1 choose then it should change colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script language="javascript">
        function changeColor(cellIndex){
            var objTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            
            var objRows = objTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
            for(var counter=1; counter<=objRows.length-1;counter++){
            
                var objCells = objRows[counter].getElementsByTagName("td");
                
                for(var cellCounter=0; cellCounter<=objCells.length-1;cellCounter++){                       
                    if(cellCounter===cellIndex){
                        objCells[cellCounter].style.backgroundColor='red';
                    }else{
                        objCells[cellCounter].style=null;
                    }                       
                }   
            }
        }
    </script>

<table id="myTable">
          <tr>
            <th>plan 1</th>
            <th>plan 2</th>
            <th>plan 3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>plan 1 detail</td>
            <td>plan 2 detail</td>
            <td>plan 3 detail</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>plan 1 detail</td>
            <td>plan 2 detail</td>
            <td>plan 3 detail</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="changeColor(0)">choose me!</td>
            <td onclick="changeColor(1)">choose me!</td>
            <td onclick="changeColor(2)">choose me!</td>
          </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: perfectly working how to remove other cloumn style when slected other

Comment: gr8. please accept this solution so that this can help others. I will modify this to remove other column styles.

Comment: java script method modified. Please check and let me know if there is any issue or not working as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are planning to create the table static and not on any loop you need to provide a static ID to each  in order to access things and do what you want. You can run the below example in the w3school in order to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Plan Name</th>
    <th>Plan Details</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <td>Basic</td>
    <td>plan 1 detail</td>
    <td><button onclick="setTable('row1')">choose me!</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row2'>
    <td>Intermediate</td>
    <td>plan 2 detail</td>
    <td><button onclick="setTable('row2')">choose me!</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row3'>
    <td>Advance</td>
    <td>plan 3 detail</td>
    <td><button onclick="setTable('row3')">choose me!</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<script>

function setTable(id) {
var row = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(row);
row.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note  : To not have two rows same background color you have to remove style or class from all other rows in your function.
Please let me know if this works. Give a thumbs up if it makes you clear.

Comment: They want to color columns, not rows.

Comment: I want to select column of plan not row suppose i click on choose me all the cloumn abouve that get style update

Comment: You just have to do it same as you were doing and use the function on the choose me click and it will be converted to columns. No issues. For tables the better way is to work with rows and not with columns so I just changed things to give it a feel.

Comment: when i click on other column then how to remove the style from other

Comment: you can simply set the style to null for rest table rows with their ids.